# Make html page don't scroll when height change smaller on mobile device

Tags: android, html, css, scroll

I want to realize 1080px * 1812px html page in one mobile device. And the page I wrote is 1080px * 1920px as the UI designed before. I don't want the page scrolls and the content must be shown in the whole page. Most content of the page is images and used absolute positions, so it's hard to change each images. In the case of no changing the images height attribute, Is there anyway to change the height to 1812px no matter the images of page are compressed?

This is the original code.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1080; user-scalable=no; target-densitydpi=device-dpi;" />
```

I tried 
content="width=1080;height=1812;" It doesn't work.

Comment: try user-scalable=no to user-scalable=yes

Comment: @NguyễnTrungHiếu I don't want the page can scale or scroll and the content should be displayed all. Can I realize it via meta tag?

Answer (score 0):

use `jquery`

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).load(function(){
   var hgt = $(document).height(); // height of the document

   if(hgt <= $(window).height()){
     $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
  } else {
     $('body').css('overflow','auto');
  }

 });
});
```

Comment: I want to let the content shows in the 1080px*1812px height device, no scroll, no hide and no scale. Can it be accomplish?

Comment: No scroll, no overflow, no scale can achieve if we use `vh` unit in values like for an example, in css `div{height:10vh;}` or any of your div with a height. All elements in your document should have a unit of `vh` and all in all should total of `100vh`

Comment: But if you have so long contents in your document, this is hard to achieve

Comment: haha I tried vh attribute conincidently. I found It can help. However there are so many images need to change size at the same time- 。-

Comment: hehe no probs :)